# redefinition errors in WinSock2.h

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, networking

Including winsock2.h, in a file of a project.

Getting many errors in -
 `WinSock2.h(109) : error C2011: 'fd_set' : 'struct' type redefinition`
with a corresponding -
 `WinSock.h(54) : see declaration of 'fd_set'`

I don't see winsock.h included in any of the headers.

Are there any setting in the project that may be causing this?

**EDIT**
However, I am using windows.h in another file:
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/41212-strange-msvc-winsock2-compile-error.html

**EDIT 2**
In the header I have:

```
#include <winsock2.h>  
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include "\MyFiles\FileX.h" <-which #include <windows.h>
```

Answer (score 70):

My educated guess would be the order of included headers, i.e. include `winsock2.h` first (with first meaning before `windows.h`), or define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before including `windows.h`, which prevents windows.h from including winsock v1.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

-or-

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
```

Comment: Jim, I would think the way I included my other header file, winsock2.h would be first? Do I have to put the winsock2 in the other file? (see EDIT 2)

Comment: Wish they would just fix this forever in visual studio!  Thanks for explaining the errors.

Comment: I'm amazed how much Windows API sucks.

Comment: @Bartek: I agree. Not exactly how much the API itself sucks, but the SDK.

Comment: +1 WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN saved my day :)

Comment: In Qt, I had multiple calls to windows.h from other 3rd party source code and only one call to winsock2.h in some new 3rd party includes. I wound up having to put DEFINES += WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN in my .pro file to fix this.  Thanks +1

Comment: if you happen to include `stdafx.h` all over the place, you can place `#include <winsock2.h>` at the begining of it. i took over some code that happen to fall under this case, and this is what saved my life

Comment: In my case, I am just including WS2tcpip.h everywhere (other 2 files are not included, because they are internally included in this one).But still I am getting redefinition error for many functions. Most of these functions are declared under #if INCL_WINSOCK_API_PROTOTYPES block which is defined to 1. Can you suggest something on this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

After some headache: I made sure that an `#include "Winsock2.h"` is before any `#include "windows.h"` and `"#include "Winsock.h"` and this solved the case.

I checked the recursive includes, I spotted the header files which include (recursively) some `#include "windows.h"` and `"#include "Winsock.h"` and write a `#include "Winsock2.h"`. in this files, i added `#include "Winsock2.h"` as the first include.

Just a matter of patience, look at includes one by one and establish this order, first  `#include "Winsock2.h"` then `#include "windows.h"`

Comment: WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN really works

Comment: @octoback nope. Not working here