# Can't include Winsock2.h in MSVC 2010

Tags: visual-c++, winsock2, visual-studio-2010

I cannot include WinSock2.h in a msvc++2010 project. At first I though it was something I was doing wrong, so I created an empty project to test my sanity. The empty project is as follows

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>


int main(void){

    system("echo Hello World");
    system("pause");
    return 0;

};
```

It compiles and works fine without the line `#include <WinSock2.h>` but it fails with a long list of errors when I do try and include WinSock2.h.

Errors:

```
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(91): warning C4005: 'AF_IPX' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(460) : see previous definition of 'AF_IPX'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(131): warning C4005: 'AF_MAX' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(479) : see previous definition of 'AF_MAX'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(168): warning C4005: 'SO_DONTLINGER' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(402) : see previous definition of 'SO_DONTLINGER'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(212): error C2011: 'sockaddr' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(485) : see declaration of 'sockaddr'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(390): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(390): error C3805: 'constant': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(524): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSA' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(287) : see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSA'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(530): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSB' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(293) : see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSB'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(536): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSC' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(299) : see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSC'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(547): warning C4005: 'INADDR_ANY' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(304) : see previous definition of 'INADDR_ANY'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(549): warning C4005: 'INADDR_BROADCAST' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(306) : see previous definition of 'INADDR_BROADCAST'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\ws2def.h(583): error C2011: 'sockaddr_in' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(312) : see declaration of 'sockaddr_in'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(132): error C2011: 'fd_set' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(68) : see declaration of 'fd_set'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(167): warning C4005: 'FD_SET' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(102) : see previous definition of 'FD_SET'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(176): error C2011: 'timeval' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(111) : see declaration of 'timeval'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(232): error C2011: 'hostent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(167) : see declaration of 'hostent'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(245): error C2011: 'netent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(180) : see declaration of 'netent'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(252): error C2011: 'servent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(187) : see declaration of 'servent'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(264): error C2011: 'protoent' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(199) : see declaration of 'protoent'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(360): error C2011: 'WSAData' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(322) : see declaration of 'WSAData'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(458): error C2011: 'sockproto' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(494) : see declaration of 'sockproto'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(500): error C2011: 'linger' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(531) : see declaration of 'linger'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(513): warning C4005: 'SOMAXCONN' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(544) : see previous definition of 'SOMAXCONN'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(542): warning C4005: 'FD_READ' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(562) : see previous definition of 'FD_READ'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(545): warning C4005: 'FD_WRITE' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(563) : see previous definition of 'FD_WRITE'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(548): warning C4005: 'FD_OOB' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(564) : see previous definition of 'FD_OOB'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(551): warning C4005: 'FD_ACCEPT' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(565) : see previous definition of 'FD_ACCEPT'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(554): warning C4005: 'FD_CONNECT' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(566) : see previous definition of 'FD_CONNECT'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(557): warning C4005: 'FD_CLOSE' : macro redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(567) : see previous definition of 'FD_CLOSE'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1578): error C2375: 'accept' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(742) : see declaration of 'accept'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1600): error C2375: 'bind' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(747) : see declaration of 'bind'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1619): error C2375: 'closesocket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(752) : see declaration of 'closesocket'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1638): error C2375: 'connect' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(754) : see declaration of 'connect'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1659): error C2375: 'ioctlsocket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(759) : see declaration of 'ioctlsocket'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1680): error C2375: 'getpeername' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(764) : see declaration of 'getpeername'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1701): error C2375: 'getsockname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(769) : see declaration of 'getsockname'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1724): error C2375: 'getsockopt' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(774) : see declaration of 'getsockopt'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1745): error C2375: 'htonl' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(781) : see declaration of 'htonl'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1762): error C2375: 'htons' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(783) : see declaration of 'htons'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1780): error C2375: 'inet_addr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(785) : see declaration of 'inet_addr'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1797): error C2375: 'inet_ntoa' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(787) : see declaration of 'inet_ntoa'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1815): error C2375: 'listen' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(789) : see declaration of 'listen'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1833): error C2375: 'ntohl' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(793) : see declaration of 'ntohl'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1850): error C2375: 'ntohs' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(795) : see declaration of 'ntohs'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1870): error C2375: 'recv' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(797) : see declaration of 'recv'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1895): error C2375: 'recvfrom' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(803) : see declaration of 'recvfrom'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1921): error C2375: 'select' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(811) : see declaration of 'select'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1945): error C2375: 'send' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(818) : see declaration of 'send'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1970): error C2375: 'sendto' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(824) : see declaration of 'sendto'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(1996): error C2375: 'setsockopt' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(832) : see declaration of 'setsockopt'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2018): error C2375: 'shutdown' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(839) : see declaration of 'shutdown'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2039): error C2375: 'socket' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(843) : see declaration of 'socket'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2063): error C2375: 'gethostbyaddr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(850) : see declaration of 'gethostbyaddr'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2083): error C2375: 'gethostbyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(855) : see declaration of 'gethostbyname'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2101): error C2375: 'gethostname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(857) : see declaration of 'gethostname'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2121): error C2375: 'getservbyport' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(861) : see declaration of 'getservbyport'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2141): error C2375: 'getservbyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(865) : see declaration of 'getservbyname'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2160): error C2375: 'getprotobynumber' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(869) : see declaration of 'getprotobynumber'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2178): error C2375: 'getprotobyname' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(871) : see declaration of 'getprotobyname'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2200): error C2375: 'WSAStartup' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(875) : see declaration of 'WSAStartup'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2219): error C2375: 'WSACleanup' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(879) : see declaration of 'WSACleanup'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2236): error C2375: 'WSASetLastError' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(881) : see declaration of 'WSASetLastError'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2253): error C2375: 'WSAGetLastError' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(883) : see declaration of 'WSAGetLastError'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2270): error C2375: 'WSAIsBlocking' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(885) : see declaration of 'WSAIsBlocking'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2287): error C2375: 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(887) : see declaration of 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2304): error C2375: 'WSASetBlockingHook' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(889) : see declaration of 'WSASetBlockingHook'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2321): error C2375: 'WSACancelBlockingCall' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(891) : see declaration of 'WSACancelBlockingCall'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2343): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(893) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetServByName'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2370): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(901) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2396): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(909) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2421): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(916) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2446): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(923) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2473): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(930) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2496): error C2375: 'WSACancelAsyncRequest' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(939) : see declaration of 'WSACancelAsyncRequest'
1>c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock2.h(2517): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncSelect' : redefinition; different linkage
1>          c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\winsock.h(941) : see declaration of 'WSAAsyncSelect'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am assuming that Microsoft would not distribute bad header files in their SDK, what's going on?

Comment: Duplicate of [redefinition errors in WinSock2.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971332/redefinition-errors-in-winsock2-h)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I believe you are getting these errors because windows.h will include winsock.h. Reverse the order of your includes so that WinSock2.h comes before windows.h. WinSock2.h has some #defines in it to keep windows.h from including winsock.h

Comment: To elaborate on this, winsock2.h is meant to be a replacement for winsock.h, they are not meant to be used together. If winsock.h is included first, winsock2.h fails to compile because it redeclares everything that winsock.h already declared. If winsock2.h is included first, it disables winsock.h for you. windows.h includes winsock2.h if `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0400`, otherwise it includes winsock.h instead.

Comment: hero!  this has been driving me nuts for 30 minutes.

Comment: thank you...this is a mess! this is the third time that drives me crazy for days! Microsoft should seriously consider fixing this :'(

Answer (score 4):

I made sure that an #include "Winsock2.h" is before any #include "windows.h" and "#include "Winsock.h" and this solved the case.

Just a matter of patience, look at includes one by one and establish this order, first  #include "Winsock2.h" then #include "windows.h"

I checked the recursive includes, I spotted the header files which include (recursively) some #include "windows.h" and "#include "Winsock.h"and write a#include "Winsock2.h". in this files, i added#include "Winsock2.h"` as the first include.