# How to compile Qt 6 sources with openssl 3.0?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, openssl

I'm trying to compile the Qt source `6.6.1` with OpenSSL 3.0, i have compiled the OpenSSL source `openssl-3.2.0`
and set it folder to the PATH variable `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL` it sucessfully enabled the 3.0 option in the config log:

```
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... no
  Using vcpkg ............................ yes
  udev ................................... no
  OpenSSL ................................ yes
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ no
  OpenSSL 3.0 ............................ yes
```

However, now when compiling the source i'm getting a lot of redefinition errors on `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h` files:

```
C:\Qt\w6.6.0>cmake --build . --parallel
[2307/19563] Building CXX object qtbase\src\plugins\tls\op...ndOpenSSLPlugin.dir\RelWithDebInfo\qtlskey_openssl.cpp.obj
FAILED: qtbase/src/plugins/tls/openssl/CMakeFiles/QTlsBackendOpenSSLPlugin.dir/RelWithDebInfo/qtlskey_openssl.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.334\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DNOMINMAX -DOPENSSL_API_COMPAT=0x10100000L -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_UP_TO=0x040800 -DQT_EXPLICIT_QFILE_CONSTRUCTION_FROM_PATH -DQT_LEAN_HEADERS=1 -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_NO_AS_CONST -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_QEXCHANGE -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_WARN_DEPRECATED_UP_TO=0x070000 -DQTlsBackendOpenSSLPlugin_EXPORTS -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 -DCMAKE_INTDIR=\"RelWithDebInfo\" -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\src\plugins\tls\openssl\QTlsBackendOpenSSLPlugin_autogen\include_RelWithDebInfo -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\src\plugins\tls\openssl -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\include -I"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\include" -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\src\network -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\6.6.1 -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\include\QtNetwork\6.6.1\QtNetwork -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\src\corelib -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\include\QtCore\6.6.1 -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\include\QtCore\6.6.1\QtCore -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\include\QtCore -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -IC:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\include\QtNetwork /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /Zi     /DNDEBUG -O2 -Ob3 -std:c++17 -MD /W3 /EHs-c- /wd4530 /wd4577 -Zc:__cplusplus -permissive- -utf-8 -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zc:ternary -Zc:externConstexpr -Zc:wchar_t -bigobj -guard:cf -Gw /showIncludes /Foqtbase\src\plugins\tls\openssl\CMakeFiles\QTlsBackendOpenSSLPlugin.dir\RelWithDebInfo\qtlskey_openssl.cpp.obj /Fdqtbase\src\plugins\tls\openssl\CMakeFiles\QTlsBackendOpenSSLPlugin.dir\RelWithDebInfo\ /FS -c C:\Qt\w6.6.0\qtbase\src\plugins\tls\openssl\qtlskey_openssl.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared\ws2def.h(103): warning C4005: 'AF_IPX': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um\winsock.h(457): note: see previous definition of 'AF_IPX'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared\ws2def.h(147): warning C4005: 'AF_MAX': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um\winsock.h(476): note: see previous definition of 'AF_MAX'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared\ws2def.h(187): warning C4005: 'SO_DONTLINGER': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um\winsock.h(399): note: see previous definition of 'SO_DONTLINGER'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared\ws2def.h(240): error C2011: 'sockaddr': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um\winsock.h(482): note: see declaration of 'sockaddr'
...
```

The full build log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/u1bAvzQe)

I'm compiling using `Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.9.0-pre.3.0` with the following command:

```
configure.bat -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -force-debug-info -webengine-proprietary-codecs -feature-vulkan -no-schannel -openssl-runtime -prefix "C:\Qt\w6.6.0"
```

After some research, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11727055) that suggests a problem in the order of the includes.

I wonder if I'm missing something in the `configure.bat` command
or if it's a problem in the Qt source code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372480/c-redefinition-header-files-winsock2-h

Comment: So is it indeed an issue in the build system, I've opened an issue here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-121419

Comment: This is probably a duplicated of [QTBUG-119417](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-119417).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue in OpenSSL 3.2, as described [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/22811). You could reinstall OpenSSL 3.2 with this [pull request](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/22813) and you should be able to compile Qt without this problem.

A 3.2.1 release fixing this problem is planned for the end of January.